# Allow writes to specific directory while running with --read-only rootfs

Tags: docker

I would like to run a Docker container with a `--read-only` rootfs while still being able to perform writes to specific folders such as `/etc/`. I need to persist the written data.

Essentially I'm looking for [this solution](https://apptainer.org/docs/user/main/persistent_overlays.html), but for Docker containers.

I have found the following two solutions, that I am however not satifisfied with.

1. Use a volume mount, e.g.:

   ```
   docker run --read-only -v overlay:/etc/ nginx
   ```

   Problem: This copies all data from `/etc/` into the host at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/overlay/_data`, which I would like to avoid.
2. Mount overlay on top of dir inside container

   ```
   $ docker run --read-only --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined -v /etc-overlay -it ubuntu bash
   root@94ec7ea3e1ac:/# cd etc-overlay/ && mkdir upper work
   root@94ec7ea3e1ac:/etc-overlay# mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/etc,upperdir=upper,workdir=work /etc
   ```

   Problem: This requires capability `SYS_ADMIN`. And from my research it seems like this cannot be dropped after the container is started.

Is there any alternative that I have missed?

Comment: Did you consider using bind mount `-v ./etc:/etc`?

Comment: @KamilCuk: That's just a variant of option 1. The goal here is to store *only* the diffs (files written to `/etc`) persistently. This requires an overlay filesystem (see option 2).

Comment: hi @MSalters my understanding is that the problem with option 1 is _only_ that the data are copied from etc into the volume. Bind mount does not make docker copy the volume content. I think "allow writes to specific directory" means just that, irrelevant of diffs.

Comment: The bind mount will overwrite whatever is at /etc with the host's content. I would like to preserve /etc from the image.

Comment: Unix in general doesn't have a concept of a file system that's read-only except for some directory.  If the root filesystem is read-only, you need to mount some writable storage on top of it.  The first option using a Docker named volume seems much more manageable than trying to directly manipulate overlayfs.